# how to refresh pyplots in wx.auinotebook

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython

In following code, when the button is clicked, I insert the plots into the tabs of an auinotebook in another frame.

for example, When I have multiple plots in the plt window, I can drag a notebook tab into the bottom (that results in displaying two plots). Later on when I delete the bottom tab, and try to go into other plots, I see a flicker like the closed tab is still there.

**I guess the issue is with my on_nb_tab_close. Because, without that I was not able to notice any such problem.**

I appreciate help. Code samples will be very useful. (wxpython version 2.812)

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.aui as aui
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as mplCanvas

def create_plotter(self):
    try:
        self.plotter.Show()
    except AttributeError:
        self.plotter =PlotFrame(self, 500, 500)
        self.plotter.Show() 
    return self.plotter

class PlotFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, height, width):         
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(height,width), title="plts")        
        self.parent=parent  
        self.nb = aui.AuiNotebook(self)    
        self.Bind(aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE, self.on_nb_tab_close, self.nb)

    def AddPlotTab(self,name="plot"):
        page = Plot(self.nb)
        self.nb.AddPage(page,name)
        return page

    def on_nb_tab_close(self, evt):
        print "tab close fired"
        s=self.nb.GetSelection()
        v=self.nb.RemovePage(s)     
        if not self.nb.GetPageCount():
            self.on_Close(evt)       
        evt.Veto()

class Plot(wx.Panel):
 def __init__(self, parent, id = -1, dpi = None, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=id, **kwargs)
        self.figure = mpl.figure.Figure(dpi=dpi) 
        self.canvas = mplCanvas(self, -1, self.figure) # wxPanel object containing plot
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas,1,wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="Plotting test", size=(300, 300))    
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Print 1")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnBtn1, self.btn1)

    def OnBtn1(self, evt):
        plotter=create_plotter(self)
        page1 = plotter.AddPlotTab("case 1: first_plot")  
        page1.figure.gca().plot(range(10),range(10),'+')
        page1.figure.gca().plot(range(10),range(10),'-',color='red')
        page1.figure.canvas.draw()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = wx.App(False)
    FRAME = MainFrame(None)
    FRAME.Show()
    APP.MainLoop()
```

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here.  Most people (my self included) are not willing to wade through that much code (that is for the most part unrelated to your actual problem).  If you can reduce this to a _minimal_ example have a much better chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I made it shorter to the best I could do!

Comment: It is still on the long side.

Comment: Thank you! I tried again. Based on your comment, while I was making the code shorter, I realize that the issue comes from on_nb_tab_close routine which I have bound to the notebook tab close. Because, it was fine without that code fired. I hope it will be easier to diagnose now.

Comment: It is good you have sorted out which function the issue is in, now remove everything else (don't need the tool bar, do you really need all the `sizer` stuff?, do you really need the plotting test?).

Comment: Thank you. I got rid of the sizers. I was actually thinking that I need those sizers. But I kept the plotting test because it allows a required number of plot tabs to be created!